# Why might a node app using Promises not return?

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using Bluebird in a CLI app.

For some reason, the app is not completing, but I can't fathom why. I've tried running in debug (in Webstorm) and pausing while it's "hung" but I get no information.

The code is of the form:

```
Promise.all([ /* promises */ ])
  .then(function () {
    return Promise.all([ /* promises */ ]);
  })

  .then(function () {
    return console.log("Done");
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    return console.error("Failed: " + err);
  });
```

The app reports `Done` and, by inspecting my database (because the promises are from SQL INSERTs), I can see everything in place.

I'm using

```
mysql.createPool();
```

from `promise-mysql` to send my queries.

How can I debug this hang? Or are there common failure modes that I could explore?

Comment: I think I can faintly remember an issue with the database driver, but I cannot find it now

Comment: Open sockets or timers that are not `.unref()` will keep your process from exiting.  There is likely something you have left open that is making node.js think you are not done yet.  This isn't a "hang".  It's node.js keeping the process alive because there is still pending activity.

Comment: @jfriend00: "Alive but doesn't do anything" is what we typically call a "hang" :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Not what I call a hang.  It's still pumping events.  If there's an interval timer running, it's still calling it's interval callback.  If there are I/O events, they are still calling their handlers.  Failure of the process to exit is a very different problem than an actual hang where nothing is running because of either an infinite loop or a deadlock of something like that.  And, you look for completely different solutions.

Comment: FYI, though it is probably cleaner to close all your active connections to enable the process to automatically exit, you can always just call `process.exit()` yourself and it will exit even if you have sockets still open.

Comment: @jfriend00 that was definitely my fallback, but I didn't want to do that just yet, in case it resulted in masking a bug

Comment: @jfriend00: I think that if there are no events, it doesn't make a difference - the event loop is infinite here, never changing the state of the application.

Comment: A debate about the definition of 'hang' is best had in [chat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may not be closing all of your mysql connections or not terminating the pool. If you're not already doing so, it would be wise to take care of that in a `.finally()` after your mysql operations:

```
pool.end();
```

As indicated in the [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#closing-all-the-connections-in-a-pool) (emphasis added):

> When you are done using the pool, **you have to end all the connections or the Node.js event loop will stay active until the connections are closed by the MySQL server**. This is typically done if the pool is used in a script or when trying to gracefully shutdown a server. To end all the connections in the pool, use the end method on the pool

Comment: "*done may be a good place*" - if connections need to be closed, it probably should go in a `finally` callback. Bluebird recommends `using`, [but promise-mysql doesn't support that](https://github.com/lukeb-uk/node-promise-mysql/issues/15)

Comment: That's the one. I'd tried that before but it caused errors. When I revisited my code, I noticed another bug that was the root of my errors.
Explicitly closing the pool in a `finally` block is the way forward here.

Comment: You might want to briefly explain what the bug was - it's a problem when you include "black boxes" in code samples that turn out to be the problem. If `pool.end()` helps but didn't actually solve the problem, while useful, you may still want to close this.

Comment: `pool.end()` *did* solve the problem.
I had a different bug that made it look like it wasn't the solution, but it's not actually pertinent to this issue.

Comment: for completeness, the problem I had was that I was closing the pool before some dangling promises had resolved.

Comment: So... to be clear... this is the correct answer to the problem described in this question

Answer (score -3):

Can you add

`.then(null, function (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  })`

Maybe it fails and you don't catch this case

Comment: He didn't.
Doc for [catch](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html),
doc for [then](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/then.html). `Then` accepts two parameters and second is `rejectedHandler`

Comment: `.catch(onRejected)` is (Bluebird features left aside) nothing but sugar for `.then(null, onRejected)`.